# R: create a loop for importing, manipulating (spatial join) of multiple files

Tags: r, loops, geospatial

I am a basic R user who needs your help. I have multiple data files that I want to process by creating a loop function; basically, import one or two files, process, and remove them; and repeat this process for several times. However, I am stuck with probably simple codes for many of you. Please kindly help me solve this.

Simply I can import and process data with a single file, followed by.

```r
test <- read.table("test.txt", header = FALSE, sep='\t', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test <- as.data.frame(test)

## prepared for spatial joining with polygon
coordinates(test) = ~ lon + lat  
proj4string(test) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")   

## Import gis polygon shapefile
ZIPshp <- readShapeSpatial("D:/data/gis/Zipcode.shp", 
                           proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")) 

## spatial join b/w point and polygon 
test_zip <- over(test, ZIPshp[,"zipc"])
test_zip <- subset(test_zip, zipc != "") 
  
write.table(test_zip, "test_zip.csv", sep = ",", na = "NA", row.names = FALSE)
```

However, I failed to figure out how to create a loop function to repeat this process in multiple times, especially, removing processed data frame after data processing is complete. Here are my trial but it still misses a key portion, which I really need your help. (I also thought about do.call and lapply functions but failed to come up with)

```r
files=list.files(pattern='*.txt')
    
ldf <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  ldf[[i]] <- read.table(files[[i]], header=FALSE, sep='\t', 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
    
  coordinates(ldf[[i]]) = ~ lon + lat
  proj4string(ldf[[i]]) = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")
}
    
## (missing parts are spatial join, removal of processed 
##  data frame, and repeating this process with new data)
```

Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below as a skeleton to complete your solution

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## Import gis polygon shapefile
ZIPshp <- readShapeSpatial("D:/data/gis/Zipcode.shp",
    proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")) 

##read in each file and process it
lapply(list.files(pattern='*.txt'), function(txtfile) {
    test <- read.table(txtfile, header=FALSE, sep='\t')

    ## prepared for spatial joining with polygon
    coordinates(test) <- ~lon+lat  
    proj4string(test) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83")  

    ## spatial join b/w point and polygon 
    test_zip <- over(test, ZIPshp[,"zipc"])
    test_zip <- subset(test_zip, zipc!="") 

    ## output processed file as a csv
    write.csv(test_zip, 
        paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(txtfile), ".csv"), 
        row.names = FALSE) 
})
```

Comment: This is great! It works perfectly. I really appreciate your kind response.